# groupby difference and percentage change

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame

```
              t_f      m_s
   uni        
   A          False    1.2
   A          True     0.6
   B          False    0.9
   B          True     0.6
```

I am trying to get the difference of True - False for each uni and also calculate the percentage change True-False/False
I am sure there is a way to do this using group by but i cant figure out how.

The output should be a data frame

```
              m_s_diff   m_s_diff_percentage
   uni        
   A          -0.6         -50%
   B          -0.3         -33.33%
```

Comment: Can you add the expected output?

Comment: `df.iloc[::2, :]['m_s'] - df.iloc[1::2]['m_s']` like this? It is not clear if this data represents your entire input and output.

Comment: this is just a snapshot of my data

Comment: `df.groupby(level=0).diff().dropna()`

Comment: @Wen, please turn it to an answer.

Comment: @MaxU Ok , but seems OP want one more column, working on that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use query.

`df.query('t_f==True').m_s - df.query('t_f==False').m_s`

Answer (score 2):

Try this ..

```
df.groupby(level=0)['m_s'].diff().dropna()


uni
A   -0.6
B   -0.3
Name: m_s, dtype: float64
```

Below are solution provided by @MaxU

```
df.groupby(level=0)['m_s'].agg(['diff','pct_change']).dropna()
Out[502]: 
     diff  pct_change
uni                  
A    -0.6   -0.500000
B    -0.3   -0.333333
```

Comment: a small tune up: `df.groupby(level=0)['m_s'].agg(['diff','pct_change']).dropna()`